# stripejs autofill does not work on chrome mobile device (samsung galaxy)

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm using `<CardElement>` and

```
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.4.1",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.17.1",
```

Only seeing this issue on chrome mobile browser (samgsung galaxy), works fine on desktop chrome.

After entering credit card info with gpay auto fill (selecting card and then entering cvv) the gpay dialog closes and the `<CardElement>` does not get updated.  I notice that the `<CardElement>` always has focus during gpay popup dialog. Anyone else experience this issue?

Comment: It may be worth writing into Stripe's support team at https://support.stripe.com/contact. If you provide screenshot/video and details on how to reproduce it'll increase the likelihood that they find the root issue and fix it.

Comment: You have any luck resolving this? It is still an issue